# Copy specified number of lines to multiple documents with a Python script that can be run from the command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

I am trying to build a script that copies a specified number of lines from one document to multiple other documents. The copied lines are supposed to be appended to the end of the docs. In case I want to delete lines from the end of the docs, the script also has to be able to delete a specified number of lines.

I want to be able to run the script from the command line and want to pass two args:

1. "add" or "del"
2. number of lines (counting from the end of the document)
   A command could look like this:
   `py doccopy.py add 2` which would copy the last 2 lines to the other docs, or:
   `py doccopy.py del 4` which would delete the last 4 lines from all docs.

So far, I have written a function that copies the number of lines I want from the original document,

```
def copy_last_lines(number_of_lines):
    line_offset = [0]
    offset = 0
    for line in file_to_copy_from:
        line_offset.append(offset)
        offset += len(line)
    file_to_copy_from.seek(line_offset[number_of_lines])
    changedlines = file_to_copy_from.read()
```

a function that pastes said lines to a document

```
def add_to_file():
    doc = open(files_to_write[file_number], "a")
    doc.write("\n")
    doc.write(changedlines.strip())
    doc.close()
```

and a main function:

```
def main(action, number_of_lines):
    if action == "add":
        for files in files_to_write:
            add_to_file()
    elif action == "del":
        for files in files_to_write:
            del_from_file()
    else:
        print("Not a valid action.")
```

The main function isn't done yet, of course and I have yet to figure out how to realize the del_from_file function.
I also have problems with looping through all the documents.

My idea was to make a list including all the paths to the documents i want to write in and then loop through this list and to make a single variable for the "original" document, but I don't know if that's even possible the way I want to do it.
If possible, maybe someone has an idea for how to realize all this with a single list, have the "original" document be the first entry and loop through the list starting with "1" when writing to the other docs.

I realize that the code I've done so far is a total clusterfuck and I ask a lot of questions, so I'd be grateful for every bit of help. I'm totally new to programming, I just did a Python crash course in the last 3 days and my first own project is shaping out to be way more complicated than I thought it would be.

Comment: You don't need Python for this.  You can use a shell script with the `head` and `tail` commands.

Comment: I have never written anything in shell, I'd have to get familiar with that first. Would it be so much easier that it would still be worth it? I'm also on Windows, so I would have to use batch, wouldn't I?

Comment: Oh, Windows doesn't have the right tools.  I'll post a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you ask, I think.

```
# ./doccopy.py add src N dst...
#    Appends the last N lines of src to all of the dst files.
# ./doccopy.py del N dst...
#    Removes the last N lines from all of the dst files.

import sys

def process_add(args):
    # Fetch the last N lines of src.
    src = argv[0]
    count = int(args[1])
    lines = open(src).readlines()[-count:]

    # Copy to dst list.
    for dst in args[2:}
        open(dst,'a').write(''.join(lines))

def process_del(args):
    # Delete the last N lines of each dst file.
    count = int(args[0])
    for dst in args[1:]:
        lines = open(dst).readlines()[:-count]
        open(dst,'w').write(''.join(lines))

def main():
    if sys.argv[1] == 'add':
        process_add( sys.argv[2:] )
    elif sys.argv[1] == 'del':
        process delete( sys.argv[2:] )
    else:
        print( "What?" )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm.
When I use the "del" option, I get a blank line at the end of the files, is there a way to delete the line break too? If I copy something again the other files will have more and more blank lines otherwise.

Comment: You shouldn't get a blank line.  It should just be the lines from the file.  We're not adding anything to it.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. I added a line break before the "".join(lines) in process_add so I could make sure the copied text always gets copied to a new line. When deleting I wanted to reverse that. Totally unneccessary of course. If I just end the original document with a line break, the code works exactly as intented. Thanks again, I really appreciate your help. Have a nice Sunday.